# How I can install phpseclib in raspberry pi 2?

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, phpseclib

I want to install phpseclib in my raspberry pi 2 (which OS is Raspbian).

I tried these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql php-pear
sudo pear channel-discover phpseclib.sourceforge.net
sudo pear remote-list -c phpseclib
sudo pear install phpseclib/Net_SSH2
sudo service apache2 restar here
```

When I type the first command, I get an error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-pgsql is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: ok thanks for telling me

Comment: I'd just use Composer. eg. install composer and then do composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~1.0

Comment: But since you're using PEAR...  the error you're getting isn't with phpseclib - it's with trying to install php5-pgsql. php5-pgsql isn't a pre-requisite for phpseclib. If all you're interested in doing is installing phpseclib I'd remove that from the apt-get line..